# Preencher Selects com base em item selecionado de outro Select

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Estou com dificuldade em filtrar dois `selects` com base em uma seleção anterior do usário. No caso, o usuário vai selecionar o cliente, e os `selects` vendedor e gerente devem só mostrar os vendedores e clientes desse cliente selecionado. Qualquer dica de como fazer ajudará bastante.

```
<?php
require('login/autenticacaoUsuario.php');
require('login/verificarAcesso.php');
require('../BDconexao/conexao.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Painel OS</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/> 

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <!--auto complete -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /> 


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="Painel-Admin.php">Grupo </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->





            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">



                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">


                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">

                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href="editandoPerfil.php"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Editar Perfil</a>
                        </li>
                         <li><a href="configuracoes.php"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Configurações</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="login/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i>Sair</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="sidebar-search">
                            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                        </li>
                      <li>
                            <a href="Painel-Admin.php"><i class="fa fa-windows"></i> Home</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="Dashboard/dash_admin.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"> </i> Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Clientes<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="cadastrar_cliente.php">Cadastrar Cliente</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="listar_clientes.php">Lista de Clientes</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                         <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-users"></i> Usuários<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="cadastrar_usuario.php">Cadastrar Usuário</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="listar_usuarios.php">Lista de Usuários</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                       <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Item<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="cadastrar_item.php">Cadastrar Item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="lista_itens.php">Lista de itens</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Ordem de Serviço<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="cadastrar_ordem_servico.php">Cadastrar OS</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="lista_os.php">Lista de OS's</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>

                         <li>
                                  <a href="gerenciamento.php"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Gerenciamento</a>
                                </li>



                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <h3 class="page-header">Cadastro de Ordem de Serviço (OS)</h3>


                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                        </br>

                                    <form role="form" method="POST" action="Ordem/cadastrar_os.php">



                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>OS Concessionária:</label> 
                                            <input type="text" name="os_conce" class="form-control" value="">

                                        </div>





                                            <p><label>Veículo: </label><span>*</span>
                                                <input type='text' name='veiculo'  class="form-control" value='' id='auto' required="" placeholder="Pesquise o veículo"></p>






                                         <!--trazer todos os clientes-->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Cliente:</label><span> *</span>


                                               <?php

                      $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();

                        $cliente = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE status='Ativo'");
                          $cliente->execute();

                           if($cliente->rowCount()>=1){         

                        echo '<select name="cliente" id="cliente" class="form-control" required="">';
                            echo '<option value="-">Selecione...</option>';

                                 foreach($cliente->fetchAll() as $res){                            

                                    $id_cliente = $res['id_cliente'];
                                    $nome_cliente = $res['nome_cliente'];                                           
                                   echo '<option data-cliente="'.$id_cliente_select.'" value="'.$id_cliente.'">'.$nome_cliente.'</option>';

                                }

                                echo'</select>';
                              }
                                ?>

                                            </div>

                                        <!--trazer todos os vendedores-->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Vendedor:</label>

                                             <?php

                      $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();

                        $vendedor = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE tipo_usuario='Vendedor' AND cliente_atuacao=:cliente");
                            $vendedor -> bindParam(':cliente',$id_cliente,PDO::PARAM_INT);

                          $vendedor->execute();

                           if($vendedor->rowCount()>=1){         

                              echo '<select name="vendedor" class="form-control">';
                              echo '<option value="0">Selecione...</option>';

                                 foreach($vendedor->fetchAll() as $res){                            


                                    $nome = $res['nome_funcionario'];                                           

                                   echo '<option value="'.$nome.'">'.$nome.'</option>';

                                }

                                echo'</select>';
                              }
                                ?>

                                        </div>





                                                <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Gerente 1:</label>

        <?php

                      $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();

                        $gerente = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE tipo_usuario='Gerente'");

                          $gerente->execute();

                           if($gerente->rowCount()>=1){         

                              echo '<select name="gerente1" class="form-control" >';
                              echo '<option value="0">Selecione...</option>';

                                 foreach($gerente->fetchAll() as $res){                            


                                    $nome = $res['nome_funcionario'];                                           

                                   echo '<option value="'.$nome.'">'.$nome.'</option>';

                                }

                                echo'</select>';
                              }
                                ?>

                                        </div>


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Observações:</label> 
                                                <input type="text" name="observacao" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="">
                                        </div>





                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Limpar dados</button>
                                        <a href="lista_os.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Listar Ordens</button></a>

                                    </form>
                                    </br>
                                    </br>



                                    </div>




    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../data/morris-data.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>




<!-- autocomplete jquery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete veiculo
    $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 1
    });  

      //autocomplete cor
    $("#auto_cor").autocomplete({
        source: "search_cor.php",
        minLength: 1
    });   


       //autocomplete marca
    $("#auto_marca").autocomplete({
        source: "search_marca.php",
        minLength: 1
    });              

});
</script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando o usuario escolher um item do select cliente você deve fazer uma requisição ajax para o servidor pedindo para que seja retornado os vendedos associados ao id do cliente selecionado. Por exemplo, crie um arquivo chamado filtar_clientes.php na raiz do seu site, com o seguinte conteudo:

```
<?php

        $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();

        $vendedor = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE tipo_usuario='Vendedor' AND cliente_atuacao=:cliente");
        $vendedor -> bindParam(':cliente',$_GET['id_cliente'],PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $vendedor->execute();

        if($vendedor->rowCount()>=1){         

            echo '<option value="0">Selecione...</option>';

            foreach($vendedor->fetchAll() as $res){                            


                $nome = $res['nome_funcionario'];                                           

                echo '<option value="'.$nome.'">'.$nome.'</option>';

            }

        }
    ?>
```

É claro que devem ser feitos alguns includes para que funcione corretamente.

E depois crie e link um arquivo javascript o final da sua pagina (logo apósa inclusão do jquery), com o seguinte conteudo:

```
<script>

$( "#cliente" ).change(function() {
  var client_id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/filtar_clientes.php',
    method: 'get',
    data: {id_cliente: cliente_id},
    success: function(dados){
        //troca conteudo do select com name igual a vendedor com os dados retornado pelo servidor (/filtrar_clientes.php)
        $('[name="vendedor"]').html(dados);
    };
  });
});


</script>
```

Isso deve resolver.